# java frame termnated (Ctrl +W )

Tags: java, keylistener

For example, the control+w tab in Chrome is terminated
Then one of the following features in Java to put what should you do?

Currently I am in that frame of each component is the key Listener to solve some better way do you think?

Comment: A `KeyListener` for each component isn't needed. Use [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead.

Comment: Please explain in more detail what the Key Bindings

Comment: "An input map binds key strokes to action names, and an action map specifies the action corresponding to each action name" -> See the example I gave you: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html

Comment: When the Key Bindings is going to use only the frame? In addition to this, each component or Key Bindings should I use?

Comment: Add the Key Binding to the JRootPane of the frame and it should respond to your KeyStroke no matter what component has focus.

Comment: If so, in what way the above code do?

Rootpane..getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("Controll"),KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("w"));

Rootpane.getActionMap();


Going to be this way?